# Use snippets inside Emmets in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet, vscode-snippets

In VS Code, I am aware that you can create custom Emmets, custom Snippets, and custom Emmets with Snippets inside them. But is there a way to write out an Emmet that has a snippet inside it, which then generates the full HTML?

I shall explain further; I have the following custom snippet:

```
{
    "Placeholder Image": {
        "prefix": "placeholder",
        "body": "https://placehold.co/${1:800}x${2:600}/${3:$RANDOM_HEX}/${4:$RANDOM_HEX}",
        "description": "Creates a placeholder image of size width x height, followed by the background and text colour"
    }
}
```

When I edit a file that's HTML compatible, I can simply type in `placeholder` and it'll generate a URL similar to the following: https://placehold.co/800x600/b23fce/6d9844 - this can then be used in an `<img>` tag as a temporary placeholder.

I then try to use this in an Emmet command, however the following:

```
img[src=placeholder]*3
```

...generates the folowing:

```
<img src="placeholder" alt="">
<img src="placeholder" alt="">
<img src="placeholder" alt="">
```

Is there a way to auto-convert where it says `placeholder` into the compiled string (in this case, the placeholder URL)?